# Fragment's Menu issues

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

[image]

Hi there, everything i click on my fragment. It adds a menu button to action bar . So if i click it 3 times. It adds the menu button 3 times..

Does anyone know where went wrong???

This is my code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent i = null;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.refresher:

        i = new Intent(this.context, CameraInfoActivity.class);

        startActivity(i);

        return true;

    case R.id.settings:

        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_indoor, menu);

}
```

and i added

```
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

at my OnCreateView .

this is my menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/refresher"
    android:menuCategory="system"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:title="@string/menu_add"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:menuCategory="system"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove this code:

```
inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
```

you're already have inflater

try to call

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

in fragment's constructor, not in onCreateView

Comment: Hi there , the problem still persist!

Comment: Hi, i tried your solution it still doesnt work. @konmik

Comment: Add more code, you problem is somewhere in a different place. Looks like you're adding this fragment several times.